# Deleting duplicate data with only one column?

Tags: sql-server, duplicates

I have a table called `create` with only one column called `name` of type `varchar(16)`.

Now I want to delete all the duplicate names and leave only one of those.

Example:

```
 name1
 name2
 name3
 name3
 name3
 name4
```

After is will be

```
 name1
 name2
 name3
 name4
```

Please advice.

I was looking around for a query but most of the available query had something to do with an index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use row_number

```
 WITH    cte
 AS 
 ( SELECT name, row_number() OVER ( PARTITION BY name ORDER BY name ) AS row_num
    FROM     yourTable
 )
DELETE  FROM cte
WHERE   row_num > 1
```

Comment: Worked but deleted all the duplicate data, not leaving atleast one. But anyways. It works enough for me :) I needed to delete the duplicate data so i can turn the column into an index.

Comment: This is wat you wanted rit .Delete the duplicate rows and keep only the unique ones !

Comment: Wrong, the first block of code will delete all rows, original and duplicates included.

Answer (score 0):

An index in MySQL is a way for the database engine to effectively partition and sort data so that your queries are more efficient. One of the things an index will allow you to do is specify that a particular column or field of data contain only unique entries. Creating such an index would prohibit the addition of data which has already been stored.

If you already have a column without an index, one way I can recommend you purge the duplicates is through the use of a temporary table. Create the temporary table by selecting all unique (distinct) names from the original table. Then delete everything in the original table, and copy the records back. At that point, consider adding an index.

Comment: Hello can I have created a temporary table for all the distinct data. What query should I use to insert them back?